# Magento2 view.xml redundant vars

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm trying to figure out what's the point in the following vars from view.xml in the Luma theme:

```
    <var name="product_small_image_sidebar_size">100</var>  <!-- Override for small product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_size">275</var>           <!-- Override for base product image -->
    <var name="product_base_image_icon_size">48</var>       <!-- Base product image icon size -->

    <var name="product_list_image_size">166</var>           <!-- New Product image size used in product list -->
    <var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>
```

I don't see they are being used in the code. Is this just an artifact or I've missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation it is possible to configure your image properties your module in, such way:

```
<images module="Magento_Catalog">
    <image id="unique_image_id" type="image">
        <width>100</width> <!-- Image width in px --> 
        <height>100</height> <!-- Image height in px -->
    </image>
</images>
```

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html

So in your own theme based on Luma, or module, you can change this settings or add new image types etc.

I also had no chance to found usage of such theme variables in my local Magento v 2.0

```
<var name="product_zoom_image_size">370</var>
```

But according to some articles it's image resizing actions right from the layout
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend-theme-architecture/ which actually the same.

And if we look at [old version of view.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0.1.0-alpha89/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/etc/view.xml) , then it looks like that is just old code style, so it's better to use new way described in current documentation.